Enumerated dataclass types: subclass or custom constructors?
I often find myself making dataclasses of enumerated type - for instance an Action dataclass that has a few parameters and can be one of several types.
I can see two ways to code this. First is to encapsulate everything into one class and provide custom constructors for convenience:
@dataclass
class Action:
    class Type(Enum):
        INVALID = 0
        GET_UP = Auto()
        GET_DOWN = Auto()
        JUMP_AROUND = Auto()

    user: str
    x: int
    y: int
    type: Type = Type.Invalid

    @classmethod
    def get_up(cls, user, x, y):
        return cls(user, x, y, cls.Type.GET_UP)

    @classmethod
    def get_down(cls, user, x, y):
        return cls(user, x, y, cls.Type.GET_DOWN)

    @classmethod
    def jump_around(cls, user, x, y):
        return cls(user, x, y, cls.Type.JUMP_AROUND)

Usage:
from pakidge.action import Action

act = Action.jump_around("muggs", 92, 5)
assert act.type = Action.Type.JUMP_AROUND
assert Action.get_up("asdf", 1, 2) == Action("asdf", 1, 2, Action.Type.GET_UP)

The other is to encapsulate at the module level and create multiple subclasses:
class Type(Enum):
    INVALID = 0
    GET_UP = Auto()
    GET_DOWN = Auto()
    JUMP_AROUND = Auto()

@dataclass
class Action:
    user: str
    x: int
    y: int
    type: Type = Type.Invalid

    def __eq__(self, other):
        """Permit comparison by value between base and subclass"""
        if not isinstance(self, other.__class__):
            return False
        return asdict(self) == asdict(other)

def GetUp(Action):
    def __init__(self, user: str, x: int, y: int):
        super().__init__(user, x, y, Type.GET_UP)

def GetDown(Action):
    def __init__(self, user: str, x: int, y: int):
        super().__init__(user, x, y, Type.GET_DOWN)

def JumpAround(Action):
    def __init__(self, user: str, x: int, y: int):
        super().__init__(user, x, y, Type.JUMP_AROUND)

Usage:
from pakidge import action

act = action.JumpAround("muggs", 92, 5)
assert act.type == action.Type.JUMP_AROUND
assert action.GetUp("asdf", 1, 2) == action.Action("asdf", 1, 2, action.Type.GET_UP)

Is there a reason to prefer one of these to the other - or another, better way to provide this kind of behaviour?

The subclasses in the second example seem weird to me. Whether Type should be in the action module scope or in the action.Action class scope is an orthogonal question IMO.


def GetUp(Action):
    def __init__(self, user: str, x: int, y: int):
        super().__init__(user, x, y, Type.GET_UP)


This doesn't make sense, as long as instances are still mutable and you could do this:
act = action.GetUp("asdf", 1, 2)
act.type = action.Type.JUMP_AROUND

Because then this reasonable expectation would be violated:
act: action.GetUp
assert act.type == action.Type.GET_UP

You could make instances immutable by using @dataclass(frozen=True) (I'm not sure if individual fields can be made read-only), but still it's the inferior design because the type field is now redundant, and you need to add the custom __eq__ implementation (and possibly other magic methods which you did not yet think about).
I would recommend using the @classmethod constructors, it's a common pattern.
